# Slow animation with large title bar

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I'm trying to set background image for my navigation bar.

```
guard let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else { return }

let size = CGSize(width: navigationBar.bounds.width,
                  height: navigationBar.bounds.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)
let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NavigationBackground").resizedImage(newSize: size)
navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)

func resizedImage(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    // Guard newSize is different
    guard self.size != newSize else { return self }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
    self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

But when I do that animation of showing navigation bar become very slow on simulator and on real device. What I did wrong?

Addition info: It looks like issue related with fact that on start screen I hide navigation bar in viewWillAppear, and then show it again in viewWillDisappear. In case when I show navigation on first screen no issue with navigation from screen to screen

Comment: may be you are using a very high resolution image have a large size thats why its getting a lag.

Comment: how you animate navigation bar? add detail for it also

Comment: I down resolution for image, not sure which resolution is OK, but all works the same

Comment: When I say animate I mean standard appear view with navigation bar